# Adding Custom Component in ListGrid, SmartGWT

Tags: java, smartgwt, listgrid

I am trying to add a custom component to the SmartGWT's ListGrid and I am able to do so, using the code below:-

```
listGrid.setGridComponents(new Object[]{
        ListGridComponent.HEADER,
        myLabel,
        ListGridComponent.BODY
});
```

myLabel is getting appeared in between the Header and the Body. However the Label is fixed, I want it to move whenever we scroll the grid horizontally. Is there anyway I could achieve that?